# JavaFX how to edit a DatePicker make changing the DatePicker Value?

Tags: javafx, textfield, datapicker

I have a DatePicker and an OnAction Handler that perform different works depending on the value of the DatePicker,the date I have to enter is a birthday date and I  have to make some work if it is a date of birth of an adult and some other work if it is a date of birth of an underage.
When I change the date using the "Date Picker Menu" my handler correctly perform the work i need , but when i edit TextField the handler not even reacts like DatePicker doesn't acknowledge of this change.
How can i make DatePicker "listening" to edit date using TextField?

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to an editor of your `DatePicker` object:

```
myDatePicker.getEditor().textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    // do something
});
```

Note, it will be triggered on each typed symbol.